# Expressing a rational function as a hyperbolic, logarithmic and other functions as needed for $x>0$

Tags: calculus

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvgMq.jpg)

Hi everyone,

I made a post earlier on how I can solve this question, everyone and myself was unsure what was asked for in this question.

I have been given another example of a similar question on what is required.

Express $\frac{x^6-1}{x^3}$  as a hyperbolic, logarithmic and other functions as needed for $x>0$

Here is the solution-

$\sinh⁡(x)= \frac{1}{2}(e^x-e^{-x})$

$2\sinh(\ln{x}^3)= 2\cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot (e^{\ln x^3}-e^{-\ln{x}^3})$
$=x^3-x^{-3}$
$=\frac{x^6-1}{x^3} $

Hence the answer is $2 \sinh(\ln{x}^3)$

For the question I am given, I have a coefficient of $81$ and I am not sure how to solve it

I have started with this

$\cosh(x)=\frac{1}{2} ( e^x+ e^{-x} )$

$2 \cosh(\ln{x}^2)= 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot (e^{ln {x}^2}+e^{-\ln {x}^2})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: $3^4=81, (3x)^4=81x^4$, consider $ \cosh( \ln(9x^2)).$

Comment: Yes! Is the answer 18cosh(ln(9x^2))?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance Fred. I was mulling over this question the whole day